# Fix default URL for hyperlink column in SharePoint 2013 list using a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I need to fix the default URL for the hyperlink column in SharePoint 2013 list using a PowerShell script. I'm trying the below PowerShell script and getting an error.

PowerShell script:

```
$myweb= Get-SPWeb http://sharepointtest/sites/test/
$mylist = $myweb.Lists["Test list"]
$myFieldName = $mylist.Fields["hyperlink"]
$defaultValue=$myFieldName.DefaultValue
$myFieldName.DefaultValue = 'https://www.google.com/'
$myFieldName.Update()
Write-Host 'complete'
```

Error message:

```
The property 'DefaultValue' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:5 char:1
+ $myFieldName.DefaultValue = 'https://www.google.com/'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:6 char:1
+ $myFieldName.Update()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Configuration Variables
$SiteURL = "http://sharepointtest/sites/test/"
$ListName = "Test list"
$FieldName="hyperlink"

#Get the Web, List Objects
$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL
$List = $Web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)

If($list)
{
    #sharepoint powershell update hyperlink field
    $Picture = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldURLValue
    $Picture.Description = "hyperlink"
    $Picture.URL = "http://sharepointtest/sites/test/Images/profile.jpg"

    #Add new List Item
    $Item = $List.AddItem()
    $Item[$FieldName] = $Picture
    $Item.Update() 

    Write-host "New Item Added Successfully!"
}
```

Comment: above script for fixing default value or not?

Comment: You need URL, not DefaultValue

Comment: i am getting this error 

Value cannot be null.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\Default.ps1:21 char:5
+     $Item[$FieldName] = $Picture
+    
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentNullException

Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid number value.
A number field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again."
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\Default.ps1:22 char:5
+     $Item.Update()

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException

Answer (score 0):

As per your description, my understanding is that you are trying to set a default value for Hyperlink field. Unfortunately, that is not possible using SharePoint UI. But still you can do that using InfoPath.edit the list in InfoPath, and then right click the Hyperlink or Picture field in the Fields panel. Select Field Properties and then you can set the default value for the field.

[image]